# NIFI to check and validate datetime column values from CSV file for format `mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. If Format matches treat as valid else invalid

Tags: datetime, validation, apache-nifi, csvreader

Sample CSV data:

> emp_name,id,street_name,datetime
> abc,123,xyz,8/23/21 18:27

schema used:

```json
{
  "type" : "record",
  "namespace" : "sample",
  "name" : "sample_test",
  "fields" : [
    { "name" : "emp_name", "type" : [ "null", "string"] , "default":null},
    { "name" : "id", "type" : [ "null", "string"] , "default":null},
    { "name" : "street_name", "type" : [ "null", "string"] , "default":null},
    { "name" : "datetime", "type":"long", "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}
  ]
}
```

```
Valid Format : MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss
```

NIFI to check (`08/23/21 18:04:01`) format for `datetime` column from CSV file
Expected: Invalid format

NIFI to check (`08/23/2021 18:04:01`) format for `datetime` column from CSV file
Expected: Valid format

Answer (score 3):

Use a **ValidateCsv** [processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateCsv/):

- `Schema`: `Null, Null, Null, ParseDate("mm/DD/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`
- `Header`: `true`